# How to remove empty String in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I know there have been a lot of questions around this topic but I didn't find any that described my problem. I have a data, with a specific column that looks like this:

`

```
ColumnA   
['meeting', '', 'delete', 'download']    
['error', 'meeting', '']     
['','application', '']
```

The values of columnA are a string NOT a list. What I want to achieve is to remove the [''] from the columnA. So it should be like this:

```
ColumnA                                                               
['meeting', 'delete', 'download']      
['error', 'meeting']      
['application']
```

I'm only a beginner so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['New'] = [str([s for s in literal_eval(x) if s!=''])
             for x in df['ColumnA']]
```

output:

```
                                 ColumnA                                New
0  ['meeting', '', 'delete', 'download']  ['meeting', 'delete', 'download']
1               ['error', 'meeting', '']               ['error', 'meeting']
2                ['', 'application', '']                    ['application']
```